# how to assign position to the inserted shapes basing on cell values

Tags: excel, vba

Depending on the cell values 
say `A1= 234` and `B1 = 435` ,

these `""A1 value =  x -coordinates "" and "B1 = y - coordinate "` .

These both cell values that which gives the position to the inserted shape (rectangle) in the excel sheet.

So when ever these values change dynamically not manually, the position of the respective shape ( rectangle) should change accordingly.

Comment: You can use the `Worksheet_Change` event and then simply set the new values for the shape (as it triggers automatically)

Comment: If the values are the result of formulas then you'd need to use the `worksheet_calculate` event

Comment: Sir really ididnt get what you are mean to say,I am new to this VBa coding,can you explain me in detail.Thank you  :-)

Answer (score 0):

Write a macro to get values from cell and set as `top` & `left` properties of the shape(rectangle in this case).

```
Sub MoveRectangle()
    With ActiveSheet.Shapes("Rectangle 1")
        .Left = Cells(1, "A").Value 'X - Coordinate
        .Top = Cells(1, "B").Value  'Y - Coordinate
    End With
End Sub
```

Then to attach this macro to event of value changed by any of these cell, you have to call this macro from `WorkSheet_Change` event. It will set this macro to trigger automatically when the cell's values changes.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Address = "$A$1" Or Target.Address = "$B$1" Then
        Call MoveRectangle
    End If
End Sub
```

Now try changing the values from `A1` or `B1`, the rectangle with name `Rectangle 1` should change its position accordingly.

If the cells' values are changed by formulae, then you have to call this macro from `Worksheet_Calculate` event.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()
        Call MoveRectangle
End Sub
```

Comment: first very thankful for your quick response.It is working when values in  cells A and B are changed manually but  ,when the values in cells A and B are changing dynamically not manually ,it is not working.

Comment: Can you add explanation what exactly you are trying to achieve. An example scenario, code could he helpful.

Comment: sorry that i couldnt make it more clear to you .here what i am asking is your code is running when the values in the cells A1 and B1 are changed manually ,the respective shape was changing its position accordingly.
Here my request is ,when the values in cells A1 and B1 are changing due to a formulae,I mean in cells A1 and B1 ,formulae was present like "A1 " (=A2 + A3) and "B1"  ( = B2 + B3 )

Comment: In this case you have to call this macro from `Worksheet_Calculate` event. Check the updated answer.

Comment: Its working,but got a problem.if i want to assign position in other sheet ,how to do.
this is working only on for sheet1 ,if want to work same in sheeet2 also ,how to do,....I dont know much about this vba.So kindly help me over this .Thank you

Comment: Thats what i meant by add more explanation earlier, add these details in question, add sample scenario like you did in your last comment when you explained cells' formula. An example could be like. you have on cell in sheet1, its value is used in another sheet in formula, and then there is third sheet which will contain shape? It needs all these clear details to understand what exactly you are trying to achieve.